# Issue while dealing refactoring some code to rich-domain model

Tags: spring-boot, domain-driven-design

I was reading about rich vs anemic domain models and wanted to convert an existing anemic domain model into a rich domain model. However, springboot `dependecy injection` is in the way. How can I fix this? What is the correct approach to refactor an anemic domain model to a rich domain model?

I though about adding a `public default constructor` but wouldn't that violate the rules for rich-domain models and also it would mean that I can't mark gameId/the list of scores as final?

## Error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in Score required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

 no qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String'
```

## Original

```
@Service
public class ScoreService {

    private final Map<String, List<BatsmanScore>> scores;

    public ScoreService(Map<String, List<BatsmanScore>> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    public List<BatsmanScore> getBatsmanScores(String gameId) {
        return scores.get(gameId);
    }

    public void storeScores(String gameId, List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores) {
        if (!scores.containsKey(gameId)) {
            scores.put(gameId, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        scores.get(gameId).addAll(batsmanScores);
    }
}

public class Score {

    private List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores;
    private String gameId;

    public Score() { }

    public Score(String gameId, List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
        this.batsmanScores = batsmanScores;
    }

    public List<BatsmanScore> getBatsmanScores() {
        return batsmanScores;
    }

    public String getGameId() {
        return gameId;
    }
}
```

Modified

```
@Service
public class ScoreService {

    private final Score score;

    public ScoreService(Score score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public List<BatsmanScore> getBatsmanScores(String gameId) {
        return score.getBatsmanScoreByGameId(gameId);
    }

    public void storeScores(String gameId, List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores) {
        score.storeGameScore(gameId, batsmanScores);
    }
}


@Repository
public class Score {

    private final Map<String, List<BatsmanScore>> scoreRepository = new HashMap<>();

    private final List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores;

    private final String gameId;

    public Score(String gameId, List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
        this.batsmanScores = batsmanScores;
    }

    public List<BatsmanScore> getBatsmanScores() {
        return batsmanScores;
    }

    public List<BatsmanScore> getBatsmanScoresByGameId(String gameId) {
        return scoreRepository.get(gameId);
    }

    public String getGameId() {
        return gameId;
    }

    public void storeScores(String gameId, List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores) {
        if (!scoreRepository.containsKey(gameId)) {
            scoreRepository.put(gameId, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        scoreRepository.get(gameId).addAll(batsmanScores);
    }
}
```

Comment: The rich domain model doesn't mean bringing the repository methods to the Domain class. You are overcomplicating things.

Comment: but having the logic of storing the data in service is not correct right? In the example mentioned, the service had the logic of adding and getting from the `map` which is not correct.

Comment: In a rich domain model the entities stop being fancy records, with all getters, setters and a few small utility methods. Any logic that naturally belongs in an entity is moved there. This has one major consequence: the USAGE of a repository is also moved into an entity. Afterall, calculating the price of a product may require accessing price rules or something. This does not mean that the repository itself moves into the entity. Spring boot does (without tricks) not support injecting repositories in an entity, so... There is that hurdle to take. Not sure how to solve that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Anemic domain model is when the business logic is in the services, but here it already is in the domain model, in the form of the `Score.addAll()` method:

```java
public class Score {

    private List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores;
    private String gameId;

    public Score() { }

    public Score(String gameId, List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores) {
        this.gameId = gameId;
        this.batsmanScores = batsmanScores;
    }

    public List<BatsmanScore> getBatsmanScores() {
        return batsmanScores;
    }

    public String getGameId() {
        return gameId;
    }

    public void addAll(List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores)
    {
        if (this.batsmanScores == null) {
            this.batsmanScores = new ArrayList<BatsmanScore>();
        }
        foreach(BatsmanScore score in batsmanScores) {
            // you can implement some more business logic here
            this.batsmanScores.Add(score);
        }
    }
}
```

However, your are messing your repository and your service. The service usually handles the use case and orchestrate operations around the repository and the domain model:

```java
@Service
public class AddScoreUseCase {

    private final IScoreRepository repository;

    public AddScoreUseCase(IScoreRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void storeScores(String gameId, List<BatsmanScore> batsmanScores) {
        Score score = repository.getByGameId(gameId);
        score.addAll(batsmanScores);
        repository.saveChanges(score);
    }
}
```

The repository is responsible to translate domain operations into the persistence. Here is an example of an in-memory persistence but you could also write a database repository, that would retrieve and store data from the database:

```java
@Repository
public class InMemoryScoreRepository implements IScoreRepository {

    private final Map<String, List<BatsmanScore>> scoreRepository = new HashMap<>();

    public InMemoryScoreRepository() {
    }

    public Score getByGameId(String gameId) {
        if (!data.containsKey(gameId)) {
            return new Score(gameId, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        return new Score(gameId, this.data[gameId]);
    }

    public void saveChanges(Score score) {
        if (!this.data.containsKey(score.getGameId())) {
            scoreRepository.put(score.getGameId(), score.getBatsmanScores());
        } else {
            this.data[score.getGameId()] = score.getBatsmanScores();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the domain model have a no args constructor? Isn’t one of the principles to expose only an all args constructor?

Comment: It depends if that model state is valid. The recommendation is that you cannot put your domain objects in a state that violates a business constraint. However, sometimes it is easier to initialize state without using a constructor. For more complex scenarii you can write a Factory instead.

Comment: could you please elaborate on "It depends if that model state is valid. The recommendation is that you cannot put your domain objects in a state that violates a business constraint."

Comment: or please point me to a relevant article/blog?

Comment: The purpose of the domain model is to ensure your operation does not violate any business constraint. If creating a Score object with null params violates constraints, it should immediately raise an exception, or prevent calling, instead of depending on an "is this model state valid?" operation. This is called *making illegal states unrepresentable* : https://dzone.com/articles/refactoring-with-types

Comment: You could also make the constructor non-public if it can be useful for technical purpose.